# How to fix navbar shrinking height when resizing page

Tags: html, css

I'm writing an app that replicates the look/feel of a desktop OS, and my navbar in the bottom of the page shrinks in height when the page is resized in height. It shrinks in such a way that it becomes unusable at a point.

I've already tried some CSS properties such as using: position: fixed, position: relative, and position: absolute. position: absolute is the one that has been the best try out of all of them. If I use any others, the navbar would stick at the top no matter what you change in the style.

```css
     body {
        /* these are for the navbar */
        top: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        /* normal styles */
        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
        color: white;
        background-color: #008080;
        font-size: 12px;
        /* without this, the page would go blank
        overflow: hidden;
        }
        ul {
        /* this is what works best */
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 96.17%;
        /* normal navbar styling.. */
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

I expected the navbar to move up normally as needed, keeping its properties. Instead, the navbar moves up while the page is resized, but it becomes thinner and thinner until it is unusable.
Here is a sample gif: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs7xm.gif)

Comment: Use `position: fixed` and `top: 0`. Use a fixed height e.g. 50px. Then use media queries to lower the height of the topbar when resize the browser window

Comment: Your comment `/* without this, the page...` is not close is that normal ?

Comment: @johanchopin this is not normal...

Comment: @SimonFranzen this also broke the page, i forgot to add this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row;
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100%;
  color: wheat;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  ul {
    transition: .2s all linear;
    height: 45px;
    max-width: -webkit-fill-available;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Help</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This only broke the navbar even more. Can you explain what you used? [Show Picture](https://ibb.co/GQgKZg3).

Comment: really? this code is breaking your navbar? anyway use position: sticky to make your navbar stick to where it is placed to. You might need to change your body css to get what you want actually.